# Google Sheet 3 days, then increment, then 3 days

Tags: date, google-sheets

It is very easy to create a list of dates auto-generated by sheets when you want to increment by one day:

```
1/15/17
1/16/17
```

can be turned into:

```
1/15/17   
1/16/17  
1/17/17   
1/18/17
```

by selecting the first two consecutive dates and then dragging down from the corner and letting it auto-populate.

I'm trying to do something similar but with 3 cells with the same date, then increment 1 day, 3 cells with the same date, then increment 1 day, etc...  Such as:

```
1/15/17
1/15/17
1/15/17
1/16/17
1/16/17
1/16/17
1/17/17
1/17/17
1/17/17
```

I cannot find a way to do this except tediously manually. Many thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write the first three dates, and then use for the fourth one the formula: `=A1+1`, where `A1` is the first of the three values you wrote before. Then copy and paste this to all the subsequent fields.

If the values are in a column, you'll have something like:

```
1/15/17
1/15/17
1/15/17
=A1+1
=A2+1
=A3+1
=A4+1
=A5+1
=A6+1
...
```

or, if they are in a row:

```
1/15/17   1/15/17   1/15/17   =A1+1   =B1+1   =C1+1   =D1+1   =E1+1   =F1+1   ...
```